# Backbone.js returning el after render via asynchronous ajax call

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

In my Backbone.js, I have the following

```
class ParentView extends Backbone.View
  el:"#main"

  childView : new ChildView

  render: =>
    $(@el).empty().append(@childView.render().el)


class ChildView extends Backbone.View

  render: =>
    $.ajax
      url:"get_data"
      success: (data) =>
        $(@el).empty().append("Child View done")
        @
```

The `ParentView` doesn't display anything, because I think the child view's `render` function does an AJAX call, and the parent view's `render` doesn't really "wait" for the AJAX to finish.

What's the common method of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nl_0's answer said. You are returning the promise from the ajax call. What you want to return, or meant to return with `@` is the child view instance. nl_0 is also way right about how you're fetching data. You're not really using backbone for what its good at if you're fetching data from ajax calls rather than using Backbones model and collection data layers. I'm going to vote his answer up because of that, but I hope the following does help explain the issue.

What's happening is:

```
class ParentView extends Backbone.View
   el:"#main"

  childView : new ChildView

  render: => 
    $(@el).empty().append(@childView.render().el)
    // because of the subtle mistakes in @childView.render() below
    // your childView never got anything appended to it.
    // @childView.render().el is undefined
    // essentially $(@el).empty().append(undefined)
    // that's why nothing shows up.


class ChildView extends Backbone.View

  render: =>
    $.ajax
      url:"get_data"
      success: (data) =>
        // @ is not a reference to your child view.
        // the value of @ has changed context
        // that means @el is undefined.
        // You're selecting $(undefined) not your views element.
        $(@el).empty().append("Child View done") 
        @ // this is not your ChildView instance
```

What you can do is:

```
 class ParentView extends Backbone.View
   el:"#main"

  childView : new ChildView

  render: => 
    // this line is actually okay if we fix @childView.
    $(@el).empty().append(@childView.render().el)


class ChildView extends Backbone.View

  onSuccess: (data) =>
    // the double arrow binds this function to the proper context
    // @ is our ChildView instance
    @$el.empty().append("GET get_data is done.")

  render: =>
    $.ajax
      url:"get_data"
      success: @onSuccess

    // return @ out here where it is the instance.
    // This is really where "Child View done".
    @
```

Sorry if I made any mistakes. My coffeescript skils are fairly unused. I think this is what you meant. Very subtle stuff, let me know if I need to edit this answer.

Depending on how long your ajax call takes you may still see a slight delay, because `childView.render().el` will be appended to the dom, before the ajax call comes back and appends it with "GET get_data is done."

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` call is asynchronous and it returns a promise, and your `render` methods returns this promise. I'd recommend you read something about asynchronousness in js to better understand this concept.

And what you want to achieve is usually done somehow like this:

```
class ChildView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    @on 'data:fetched', @render

  render: =>
    @$el.html("Child View done")
    @

  fetch: =>
    $.ajax
      url: "get_data"
      success: (data) =>
        # process data and attach it to view
        @trigger 'data:fetched'
```

BTW it is considered better practice to put all the data access / manipulation logic into model layer: models and collections. In this case you could do something like this:

```
class ChildView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    @collection.on 'reset', @render
    # call @collection.fetch() somewhere
    # or use @model.on 'change', @render to bind rendering to model changes

  render: =>
    @$el.html("Child View done")
    @
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical Backbone pattern for achieving this would be as follows:

```
render: =>
  $.ajax
    url:"get_data"
    success: (data) =>
      #when the ajax call returns, modify the contents of the view's el
      @$el.empty().append("Child View done")

  @ #return this
```

Basically your `render` method just kicks off the ajax request and returns control back to the caller immediately. When the ajax request returns, the *contents* of the view are modified, but the view's element doesn't change.

This means that when your parent view appends `childView.el` into its own, it doesn't matter whether `childView.render` is synchronous or asynchronous. The root element  `el` exists, whether or not it already has contents:

```
@$el.empty().append(@childView.render().el)
```

It's also important to use the [`view.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) property, instead of wrapping `view.el` with a jQuery selector (`$(@el)`). The former will work whether or not the view's element exists in the DOM, whereas the latter will fail, if the parent view is not fully rendered by the time the ajax request succeeds.